# Screensaver does not start on OS X 10.9.2

Tags: macos

My Mid-2011 iMac (Intel i5) does not start the screensaver or put the display to sleep after updating to OS X Mavericks 10.9.2. I updated to the public edition available from the Mac AppStore.

Below you can see the settings for the screensaver. Not even the hot corners will turn it on. And pressing the hardware sleep button doesn't work either. Ideas?

[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I am having the same problem, no matter what screen saver I choose.

Comment: The message screen saver works for me on all the 10.9.2 Macs I have. If you set your start time short (2 min is fine), change to the message saver and then restart your Mac - then open Console.app and search for the word screen and see what happens when the hot corner is entered or the time expires for a normal screen save event?